# What is the difference between Trappist beer and Abbey Beer?

Tags: history, trappist

Abbaye Bier (Abbey Beer) refer to monastic beer brewed by monks. And there is almost Trappist beer brewed by monks but specifically from Trappist monasteries.

**But what is the difference in terms of brewing process, resulting product and historically, why are they different?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Trappist beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trappist_beer) is a designation of the origin of the beer, rather than a designation for the style.  That is, it must come from one of the ten Trappist monasteries [recognised by the International Trappist Association](http://www.trappist.be/en/pages/trappist-beers).  There are similarities between the styles produced by these monasteries, but if one decided to make something in a completely different style it could presumably still be called a Trappist beer.

In contrast, the term [abbey beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_in_Belgium#Abbey_beers) is used to refer to any beers produced in the style of the Trappist monasteries.  It isn't necessarily produced by a monastery, and some beers produced by major breweries could be described as abbey beer.

It is kind of like the difference between "Champagne" and "sparkling white wine".

Comment: 100% correct and well stated.